# Cache Data on a RESTEasy Web Server?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, resteasy

What is the best way to cache data on a RESTeasy web server?  Can someone please give a brief example?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is too general.  You need to give some more specifics about what you are doing and what technologies / constraints you have before we can give useful answers.

Comment: I was sure that using the term RESTEasy would be sufficient, and it was, since I got my answer.  But thank you, I will write more information next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use ehcache. http://ehcache.org/
One of the things I like is that it can be persistent.